# Upload image to heroku using react native

Tags: express, react-native, heroku

i am trying to upload image from react native to heroku express app in public/images/ folder. It showing me the success message but there is no image in the images folder. 
Meanwhile when i try this code on localhost, that works fine..

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let imageFile = req.files.photo;
    let fileName = Date.now();
    let imgName = fileName+req.files.photo.name;
    let dirName = __dirname.replace('routes','public')
    dirName = dirName+'/images/';
    let path = dirName+imgName;
    imageFile.mv(path, (err)=> {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(501).json({
                message: 'error'
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'success'
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), and you cannot use it to persistently store anything at run time.
Instead, you can use an add-on from the [Heroku Elements marketplace](https://elements.heroku.com/) to implement your storage needs.
For your specific use case, [Cloudinary](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary) sounds like it might be a good match. Their Free plan gives you 10 GB of storage.
You can easily upload an image to cloudinary from your node.js code, as described [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload).

Comment: but i already have application running on heroku which is working fine..

Comment: Your application will still run on Heroku. You simply need to add a free add-on to your Heroku app, and add a few lines of code to upload your images to Cloudinary.

Comment: Amazon S3 is another popular option. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3